# Using Excel data validation lists in child tables to update parent tables also using the same data validation list

Tags: excel, list, validation, powerquery, excel-tables

Good morning, and thank you in advance.

Let me begin by saying I am a novice.

**Summary:**

I'm using a data validation list at column J ("Outbound Coach") in Table A to determine which records appear in Tables B and C.

[Table A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gtqc1.png)

Depending on which "Outbound Coach" users choose, will determine on how the results appear in Tables B and C. In this instance, there is one person on "MB1 - Coach One" and three people on "MB1 - Coach Two". To get these results I am using Power Query Editor to filter results from Table A.

[Tables B & C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRjOY.png)

If a user decides to change the coach allocation in Table A, so there are now two people on "MB1 - Coach One" and two people on "MB1 - Coach Two":

[Table A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZ2fp.png)

That change is updated and accurately reflected in Tables B & C (Through Power Query Editor and its filter function):

[Tables B & C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKLuW.png)

I have applied the same data validation list (as mentioned in Column J of Table A) to Column F in Table B and Column M in Table C.

Here is what I would like to be able to achieve, preferably without using VBA:

If a user updates a cell value in, for example, Column F of Table B, from MB1 - Coach 1 to MB1 - Coach 2, that change should be reflected in all appropriate Columns of all respective Tables.

At the moment, if a user changes the coach allocation in Tables B or C, rather than the record moving from Table B to Table C, the record remains in the same Table with the amended coach allocation. Resulting in this:

[Tables B & C - Current Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8Vwy.png)

Rather than this:

[Tables B & C - Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0g3kX.png)

I am most grateful for any advice the community may be able to offer and I am on hand to answer any follow questions should anything clarifying.

Comment: I couldn’t follow your explanation. Maybe it’d help if you [edit] your question and add pictures describing a specific event with a before and after

Comment: @RicardoDiaz. Thank you for the reply; I have added an example and thrown in some images, which will hopefully help better explain my query.

Comment: I've reread this 10 times. I'm sorry. No luck. It'd be easier if you simplify this and say something like if I change this in this table, validation in column x should change to this. Also, remember to include the headers in your images, otherwise, referring to column J it's indecipherable.

Comment: @RicardoDiaz; Should I refer to the sheet in which a table sits, or ignore the sheets and refer only to tables?

Comment: if you want to tables with column headers it's ok. but try to simplify the question as much as you can

Comment: @RicardoDiaz I hope this edited phrasing makes more sense.

Comment: Getting close. So table b should be holding all coaches one. And c all coaches two. And both tables are dependent from table A. What I don’t get is the order tables are updated. Is A only updated once by hand by the user? Otherwise if B is updated by hand and then filtered by power query, two changes are happening simultaneously.

Comment: Changes are made in Table A initially and that ability would ideally be retained, but users would like to update Tables B and C, with changes reflected in all Tables. Does this make sense?

Comment: I believe a VBA solution would be required

Comment: I had hoped that would not be the case; if I were to create a dummy version of the workbook I am working on would that make it easier to highlight what I am hoping to achieve?

Comment: We can give it a try. But sounds like you have a circular reference there